# windows 10 виснет приветствие

Tags: windows, windows-10

Привет всем. Неожиданно при включении ноута lenovo с windows 10 начало виснуть на экране приветствия. Точнее не совсем виснуть, мышка двигается, могу нажать выключение/перезагрузку, но войти в пользователя не даёт.
Что можете посоветовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Максимум могу часики отдрагендропить вверх за пределы экрана

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте загрузиться в `Safe Mode`, если войдет нормально, перегрузите в обычный режим.

Comment: Даже в безопасный режим не получается загрузиться...перепробовал все советы из инеиа

Comment: ctrl+alt+del работает? диспетчер вызывается? что если зайти под другим пользователем?

Comment: почему ? также не входит в рабоий стол?

Comment: Нее, не получается инициализировать безопасный режим. Пробовал зажимать shift перед перезагрузкой и F8 перед загрузкой системы..

Comment: Скорее всего, по какой-то причине не запускается Windows Explorer. Попробуйте `Ctrl+Alt+Del = > Task Manager` , `File = > Run new task` и запутить команду `explorer`.

Comment: При нажатии alt+cttl+del пропадают часики, но через 20 сек возвращаются назад. Так он не спрашивает имя пользователя, нет такого окна, куда его ввести. Раньше по сканеру отпечатка пальца пускало или при вводе пароля, сейчас ни то ни другое не работает

Comment: Не запускается диспетчер, я бы с радостью сделал то, о чем говорите. Что я могу запустить так это экранную клаву и лупу из специальных возможностей

Comment: А какой модель Lenovo у Вас? Скорее всего F8 не поможет, нужно выключить, потом включить не с обычной кнопки, а найти с левой (или с правой) стороны маленькую кнопку для запуска в безопасном режиме.

Comment: Lenovo v310, да, знаю про эту кнопку, уже пробовал, но безопасный режим через неё не получилось запустить. Там были только варианты: Normal startup, bios setup, boot menu и system recovery. При запуске последнего происходит обычная загрузка

Comment: В `boot menu` нужно войти, там безопасный режим (Safe Mode).

Comment: В boot menu тоже его нет...там только ubuntu, hdd, dvd-rw, network и windows boot manager, при выборе которого опять же обычная загрузка

Comment: Проще уже переустановить систему.